# How to solve error 91 on function return

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a macro that's linked to TFS queries. At some point, I use a function that refreshes each result sheet, and after that, I'm needing to know the table range, therefore my code looks like this:

```
Function RefreshQuery(shtTFSExcel_Name As String) As Range
Dim activeSheet As Worksheet
Dim teamQueryRange As Range
Dim refreshControl As CommandBarControl
Dim lr As Integer, lc As Integer

Set refreshControl = FindTeamControl("IDC_REFRESH")
  If refreshControl Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find Team Foundation commands in Ribbon. Please make sure that the Team Foundation Excel plugin is installed.", vbCritical
    Exit Function
  End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set activeSheet = ActiveWorkbook.activeSheet
Set teamQueryRange = Worksheets(shtTFSExcel_Name).ListObjects(1).Range
teamQueryRange.Worksheet.Select
teamQueryRange.Select
refreshControl.Execute
activeSheet.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

lr = teamQueryRange.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lc = teamQueryRange.Rows(2).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Set RefreshQuery = Cells(lr, lc)

End Function
```

Now, when I run it, it's working fine, until it reaches the `End Function` statement, returning error code 91 (I'm watching over `RefreshQuery`, which creates the expected range). I can't figure what's making it fail, as it's using the `Set` statement to assign the object, and I have a Range variable to get the result of the function.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that those values are found, i.e. that lr and lc are actual numbers?

Comment: Also, you'd do well to get rid of the `teamQueryRange.Worksheet.Select`, `teamQueryRange.Select` and `activeSheet.Select` and just change your `Set` to `Set RefreshQuery = teamQueryRange.Cells(lr, lc)` or similar.

Comment: @SJR, yes, that's exactly the reason I've set a watch over `RefreshQuery`, to verify those values are correctly assigned

Comment: @CLR Good observation! I just used the code for refreshing the query, and hadn't noticed I wouldn't need those instructions in the end

Answer (score 0):

Check if teamQueryRange is Nothing, in this case refresh set teamQueryRange.

Comment: Verified, it's not Nothing. I also noticed that, before running `Set RefreshQuery = teamQueryRange.Cells(lr, lc)`, I get a pair of values (lr and lc) for the range, but once assigned, the new range has values (lr+1, lc). Could this explain the error shown?